# How tanh has to do with nonlinearity

Tags: nonlinearity

I was reading an article about image processing and I came across `sigmoidal activation function` and `tanh` like in this article:

[image]

But I'm struggling to understand the concept behind the nonlinearity here and what has to do with `tanh`, could anyone clarify this idea, please

Answer (score 2):

A linear function looks like a line. Any function in the form $f(x) = ax+b$ is linear. Any function which is not linear is a non-linear function, or a nonlinearity. If you plot tanh, it's very clearly nonlinear.